# Clear resource cache via REST in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

Is there a way to clear the Geoserver resource cache using REST? Same as "Server status" > "resource cache" > "clear" in the Admin UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao Bruno,
I think that what you need is the REST call describe in this GeoServer documentation page:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/reset.html

Notice that you need to be an administrator to perform this call.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly it! Do you know, what exactly is the difference to reload? http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/reload.html

Comment: Reload does a full reload of the configuration in memory cleaning also the caches. It is needed in case of master/slave clustering with shared data directory whenever the config is changed on the master to force slaves to reload the configurationg to pick up the change.

In the end reload includes reset but at the cost of reloading the entire config, with all the implied checks and costs (e.g. connections pools and so on).

Comment: Thanks :-) so reset should be the right choice, if I add a resource (font) to the /styles directory

Comment: To be honest, I would have to check if loading a new Font requires a reset or a reload. I believe you can do a quick test yourself and report the answer here to close the loop.

Comment: works fine. in order to add a font to geoserver putting it in /styles directory and reseting the cache is sufficient. Thanks again for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GeoWebCache REST API](https://docs.boundlessgeo.com/suite/1.2.0/geoserver/geowebcache/rest/layers.html) on a layer:

```
DELETE /geoserver/gwc/rest/layers/WORKSPACE:LAYER
```

That would delete the cached layer, still leaving the GeoServer layer untouched.

Mind the extra `gwc/` in the REST path, and that layer names require the GeoServer workspace to be prepended.